# How to get 2 dates excluding weekend using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce

I tried to add this code, but it doesn't exclude weekends.

```
add_action("woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button", "custom_shipping_estimate");
function custom_shipping_estimate(){
$date1 = date("F j",strtotime("+ 2 days"));
$date2 = date("F j",strtotime("+ 4 days"));
echo "Arrives between $date1 and $date2";
}
```

Comment: well, you need to calculate whether a weekend is occuring in the timeframe and adjust your times accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strtotime `weekday` [date time formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

```
add_action("woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button", "custom_shipping_estimate");
function custom_shipping_estimate(){
    $date1 = date("F j",strtotime("+ 2 weekday"));
    $date2 = date("F j",strtotime("+ 4 weekday"));
    echo "Arrives between $date1 and $date2";
}
```